# Stream audio from Microphone in IOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, avaudiosession

I am trying to get audio from the microphone and stream it across as data through socket to a node server. Since I haven't really done this before, I am confused on how to do this properly.

First of all, how do you actually stream data from a specific microphone? I need the audio to be streamed, not recorded then sent. In other words, it needs to be like a call, where the word you say is automatically sent to to the recipient rather than recorded, then sent as some sort of recording.

Second of all, how do I specify where the audio comes in? I have seen some questions about this but I couldn't find a good solution to how to do this, especially for my case, where the audio input is from the lightening audio.

I couldn't find a good example of how to do this using AVAudioSession. Is there any good resources (examples, tutorials) that I can use to help me?

Thanks!